# How to get plotly::ggplotly to not convert boxplot x-axis labels to numeric values

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I would like to understand how I can get `plotly::ggplotly` to keep the **x-axis** labels and not convert them to numeric values? I converted the column in my `data.frame`, used for the `x-axis` labels, to characters to ensure they **are not** factors. What happens is the following:

- The first plot below (`ggplot`) shows the x-axis labels displayed correctly.
- Using the `ggplot` object above, `plotly::ggplotly` is called and the results are that the x-axis labels are displayed incorrectly (as numeric values).
- The third plot shows the same data plotted using `plotly` directly (i.e. **not** using `plotly::ggplotly`); this displays the correct results.

I would like to know how I can get `plotly::ggplotly` to display the x-axis labels correctly?

I have done some searching for this but didn't find anything.

Here are some of the key versions (packages, OS, etc.):

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

[1] plotly_4.9.0
[1] ggplot2_3.3.0
```

**Correct X-Axis Labels**

```
library(dplyr)
### Convert "Species" column to character (i.e. ensure it is NOT a factor).
iris.v2 <- iris %>% dplyr::mutate(Species = as.character(Species))
str(iris.v2)

### Shows that Species is a "chr" type.
# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
# $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
# $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
# $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
# $ Species     : chr  "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" ...

### Correct x-axis labeling: Plot data using ggplot.
plt.iris <-
  iris.v2 %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(as.character(Species), Petal.Width)) +
  ggplot2::geom_boxplot()
plt.iris
```

[image]

**Incorrect X-Axis Labels**

```
### Incorrect x-axis labeling: plot above plot with ggplotly.
pltly.iris <-
  plotly::ggplotly(plt.iris)
pltly.iris
```

[image]

```
### Correct x-axis labeling: Plot data using plotly directly.
native.pltly.iris <-
  plotly::plot_ly(iris.v2, x = ~Species, y = ~Petal.Width, type = "box")
native.pltly.iris
```

**Correct X-Axis Labels**

[image]

Comment: It coming perfectly for me.

Comment: @Mohanasundaram Let me add the versions of my packages to my question.

Comment: I added the R version and the `ggplot2` and `plotly` package versions. Also, the Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the version of `plotly`; updating from `plotly_4.9.0` to `plotly_4.9.2.1` fixes the issue. It is possible that any version of `plotly` after `4.9.0` may fix the issue, but I have not tested that, I can only confirm that `4.9.2.1` fixes the issue for me.

[image: Fixed-X-Axis-Labels-Plot]